# White Dancer Riddle

Tags: riddle

Given the following properties, what am I?

- I'm white.
- I can dance although I typically don't.
- I can be bound to a contract.
- I am rubbed frequently before I am seen and thrown away.
- I am a inanimate object.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Is this ..

> **Paper**?
> It is white, I can dance the "paper dance", bills are written on it, I can use a rubber if I did something wrong with a pencil and I'm not alive, for sure!

Comment: Also my first guess, congrats...

Comment: I was thinking more along the lines of dancing in the wind however I suppose either will suffice. Congrats.